# SVN Pre Commit search for a string in file

Tags: bash, svn, tortoisesvn, pre-commit-hook

I am trying to create a pre commit hook for a SVN repo that will prevent a commit if the version number contains 7.5

```
VERSIONNUM="<COMMENT>7.5"
grep -Fwq "$VERSIONNUM" APP.CFG
    then
    exit 1
    else
    exit 0
    fi
```

The version number is located in the APP.CFG file and the start of the line is 7.5. I do not want to match the entire line which is why I am using -w in my grep which I think just returns a match if $VERSIONNUM is located anywhere in the file

here is the contents of the APP.CFG file

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <APP AUTH="" PRODUCTS="2"
> VER="hmidesigner"> <VERSION AUTHOR="CODRA" DATE_NEUTRAL="01/11/2019
> 09:48:48" ID="CODRA.Panorama.Persist" SERIAL_VERSION="7">
> <COMMENT>7.5.17.0</COMMENT>
```

Comment: So what is not working now?

Comment: It does nothing at the moment allows every commit regardless if it is version 7.5 or not

Comment: So the `APP.CFG` contains one line as `7.5`? Why are you searching with the `<COMMENT>` string?

Comment: Because the APP.CFG file contains other information and it is possible that it could contain 7.5 elsewhere but it will never contain <COMMENT>7.5 unless it is referring to the version number

Comment: script is not valid because `if` keyword is missing for `if then else fi` construct, try adding `if ` before grep

Comment: @JoshuaDavidson: It is still not clear. Is `<COMMENT>` a literal string or your are referring it for some generic text. Show us a clear sample of the file to explain your problem

Comment: @Inian Sorry for the confusion the <COMMENT> is just plain text in the APP.CFG file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work with a slightly different approach than what I was originally going for

```
SVNLOOK diff -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | grep -i "<COMMENT>7.5." > /dev/null && { echo "Trying to Commit version 7.5" 1>&2; exit 1; }
    exit 0;
```